# Still simpler proof of the Tietze extension theorem in metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Consider

- A metric space $(X,d)$.
- A closed subset $A\subset X$.
- A continuous function $f\colon A\to\mathbb{R}$.

It is known that there are simple and explicit proofs for the Tietze extension theorem in metric space, which states that

> There is a continuous function $\overline{f}\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\overline{f}\vert_{A}=f$.

For example, if we assume $A\neq\emptyset$ and $f(A)\subset[0,1]$,
Hausdorff's explicit extension is given by
$$
\overline{f}(x)
:=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
f(x)&\text{for $x\in A$},\\
\displaystyle
\inf_{a\in A}\biggl(f(a)+\frac{d(x,a)}{d(x,A)}-1\biggr)&\text{for $x\in X\setminus A$}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
There are still many explicit extensions as stated in [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02955).

However, what is a bit strange for me is that all explicit extensions quoted in [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02955) seems requiring that the original function $f$ is "bounded", i.e. taking values only in a given interval (probably, these are somehow required to prove the continuity of extension). Of course, we can use some explicit homeomorphism between $(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ to convert the range of $f$ to $(0,1)$ and then "cut-off" the values $0,1$ using the explicit extension once more, e.g. as answered in [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4390469/an-extension-theorem-on-metric-spaces). However, from my personal aesthetic view of point, this artificial "unbounded–bounded" trick seems a bit clumsy and I want to get an "at once" explicit extension.

Thus, my questions are:

Q1. Why most of the explicit Tietze extension requires $f$ to be bounded?

Q2. Are there any simple explicit Tietze extension in metric space available
for all $f\colon A\to\mathbb{R}$ without the range restriction?

Comment: About Q1. Let $X=[0\mathbin;+\infty\mathclose[$ and $A=X\setminus\{0\}$. Define $f(t)=\frac1t$ for $t\in A$. Then $f$ isn't bounded, and it's impossible to define any $\bar f$.

Comment: @jpboucheron Well, why A is closed?

Comment: Indeed my impulsive answer was somehow careless. I suggest this explanation: most of the techniques used to extend to $X$ a function defined on $A$ make use of the boundedness of $f$; but this extra assumption does not lose in generality since the unbounded case can be made to fit into the bounded one (as indicated in the [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4390504) you already mentioned).

Comment: Well, my question asks what is the (preferably essential or main) source or reason of the requirement on the boundedness... I want to extract the common unavoidable(?) feature of extension techniques and show that this common feature requires the boundedness.